# Google Tasks is redirecting to a different link now?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, tasks

I have this link bookmarked: https://mail.google.com/tasks/ig?pli=1

but now it redirects to:
https://gsuite.google.com/learning-center/products/apps/keep-track-of-tasks/#!/

Anyone know a work around for using Google tasks in a desktop browser (other than add-ons/extensions)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Even in Chrome, the normal path to G Tasks (I was having it open as a separate window on my desktop) redirects to this

Comment: Thanks for the help w/ realizing it wasn't just firefox

Comment: No problem. Turns out G Tasks can only be accessed via Gmail or Calendar now, never stand alone. My solution is to have it open via Calendar, but then minimize the width of the browser window so that only the Tasks sidebar shows.